# Effectively using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm given a `List<String>` in which I've name and marks (double represented as string) of students. The name occur at even indices and the marks occur at odd indices. The list is something like: `["A", "6.3", "A", "1.4", "B", "6.3", "B", "8.2", "C", "4.2", "C", "3.3", "D", "3.2"]`. (Assume that the given list is well-formed.)

I want to compute each student's average and find the highest of those averages. I've tried to do it using Java Stream API. Here's my approach:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "2.5",
        "A", "6.3",
        "A", "1.4", // A's avg is 3.4
        "B", "6.3",
        "B", "8.2", // B's avg is 7.25
        "C", "4.2",
        "C", "3.3", // C's avg is 3.75
        "D", "3.2",
        "D", "2.4", // D's avg is 2.8
        "E", "7.1",
        "E", "9.6" // E's avg is 8.35
);

double maxAvg = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Person(list.get(i), Double.parseDouble(list.get(i + 1))))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .mapToDouble(set -> set.getValue()
                .stream()
                .mapToDouble(Person::getMarks)
                .average()
                .getAsDouble())
        .max()
        .getAsDouble();

System.out.println(maxAvg);
```

The `Person` class looks like this:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    double marks;

    Person(String name, double marks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public double getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I get the correct result using the above code. But **I was wondering if we can simplify it, and I want to know if I'm over-complicating anything in this**. Is there any better alternate approach to do this?

Can we somehow get rid of the `Person` class?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests to review nicely written working code should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you change the source data? Interweaving two pieces of data is a suboptimal starting point.

Comment: Having said that, the code isnt bad. One could argue if parts of it should go into distinct helper methods with nice telling names, like "turnIntoPersons()" that would return a stream of person objects for example.

Comment: Another way to just improve this code could have been `double maxAvg = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Person(list.get(i), Double.parseDouble(list.get(i + 1))))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Person::getMarks, (a, b) -> (a + b) / 2.0))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .orElse(Double.NaN);`

Comment: @shmosel we just need to get the maximum average - nothing fancy.

Comment: I've updated the question, and now I just don't need to know if my approach is good, but also can we get rid of the `Person` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `Person` class. You can group by the names directly:

```
Collection<Double> averages = IntStream.range(0, list.size() / 2)
        .map(i -> i * 2)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list::get,
                Collectors.averagingDouble(i -> Double.parseDouble(list.get(i + 1)))))
        .values();
double maxAverage = Collections.max(averages);
System.out.println(maxAverage);
```